# z-index in ie7 not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Cannot sort out a solution to give a z-index to a DOM element in ie7.
Ok this is real markup:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<div class="push"></div>
<footer id="footer-container" class="source-org vcard copyright">
<div class="grass"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</footer>
```

Here CSS:

```
#page-wrap {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
}
.push {
    height: 60px;
}
#footer-container {
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.grass {
    background-image: url("assets/images/grass.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 82px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -78px;
    width: 100%;
}
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
#footer {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Hope it helps.
Actually thi is working fine on all browser, even ie9 and ie8.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 3):

Well you didn't provide enough code and use of z-index so my logical guess is the problem with ie7 is wrong z-index interpretation. To solve your problem give negative z-index to the element you want beneath. For example,

```
<div style="z-index:-1;" id="beneath"></div>
<div style="z-index:1;" id="above"></div>
```

would work but,

```
 <div style="z-index:0;" id="beneath"></div>
 <div style="z-index:1;" id="above"></div>
```

will not work in ie7.

**So to make it work give negative value to the beneath(*whatever you want "below") div**

Answer (score 0):

I found something mysterious about IE
IE cant read z-index value more than 1000